# PHP echo the html tag is not at the corresponding place

Tags: php, html

There is two php file

The first php is header.php

```
<div class="container" id="header">
    <div id="btnGroup">
    <?php
    function setLink($link,$title){
        echo "<a href='$link'>$title</a>";
    }
    ?>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="banner">
    <img class="container" src="images/index_1.gif" />
</div>
```

The second is index.php

```
    <body>
<?php 
    require_once ('header.php'); 
    setLink("#goal","title1");
    setLink("#history","title2");
?>
<div class="container" id="center">
        <img id="history" src="images/intro/intro_01.gif"/>
</div>
<?php require_once ('footer.php'); ?>
</body>
```

The setLink() is to echo the html tag, I thought the result will be :

```
<div id="btnGroup"><a href="#goal">title1</a>....</div>
```

However, it actually turn out to be:

```
<div id="btnGroup"></div><div class="banner">..</div><a href="#goal">title1</a>
```

Why is that and how to fix? Thanks for helping

Update:

Also , The setLink should be able to call in different php

e.g. for the product.php , I can call setLink("#product","product");

Thanks

Comment: it'll output wherever you call `setLink`, not wherever `setLink` is defined.

Comment: You should call the function to the place at which you want to print the data. You can define the function wherever you want in the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call the function to the place at which you want to print the data. You can define the function wherever you want in the document.
I have rewritten your code.

```
<?php
    function setLink($link,$title){
        echo "<a href='$link'>$title</a>";
    }
?>
<div class="container" id="header">
    <div id="btnGroup">
    <?php
        setLink("#goal","title1");
        setLink("#history","title2");
    ?>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="banner">
    <img class="container" src="images/index_1.gif" />
</div>
The second is index.php

    <body>
<?php 
    require_once ('header.php');   
?>
<div class="container" id="center">
        <img id="history" src="images/intro/intro_01.gif"/>
</div>
<?php require_once ('footer.php'); ?>
</body>
```

Comment: for that you should be include/require the file header.php(the file in which the setlink function is defined) in that file.

Comment: Otherwise you need to define the function in each page where you need to call the function. But its not a good practise.

Answer (score 1):

You are **defining** setlink in the header, but where you define the function is irrelevant to where the link appears.

You are **calling** setlink in a location that is where the link is appearing.

Modify your code as follows:

header.php

```
<?php
    function setLink($link,$title){
        echo "<a href='$link'>$title</a>";
    }
?>
<div class="container" id="header">
    <div id="btnGroup">
    <?php setLink("#goal","title1");
          setLink("#history","title2"); ?>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="banner">
    <img class="container" src="images/index_1.gif" />
</div>
```

index.php

```
    <body>
<?php 
    require_once ('header.php');
    // Do not call setLink here, it's called in the header include....
?>
<div class="container" id="center">
        <img id="history" src="images/intro/intro_01.gif"/>
</div>
<?php require_once ('footer.php'); ?>
</body>
```

Comment: I think his overall goal is to set different links on each page though, so call `setLink` from the individual pages and have them appear in the common header.

Comment: @sevenseacat - not sure where you're getting that idea.  I don't see that in the question at all.

Comment: oh I could be wrong, but that's the impression I got.

Comment: Yes, what if I would like to setLink in different page? thanks

Answer (score 1):

You defined function instead of calling it.
Change the code as below for header.php:

```
<div class="container" id="header">
    <div id="btnGroup">

    <?php
     setLink("#goal","title1");
     setLink("#history","title2");
    ?>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="banner">
    <img class="container" src="images/index_1.gif" />
</div>
```

You can define function setlink in index.php. Place the function definition anywhere in the file, for example at the bottom of the index.php

```
<body>
<?php 
    require_once ('header.php'); 
?>
<div class="container" id="center">
        <img id="history" src="images/intro/intro_01.gif"/>
</div>
<?php require_once ('footer.php'); ?>
</body>

<?php
 function setLink($link,$title){
      echo "<a href='$link'>$title</a>";
 }
?>
```

Comment: make an func.php file, define in it the function setlink or any other function you need to be able to call from any page and include it in every page you want.